# How to append records to table in local storage

Tags: javascript

How do I append records to a table in local storage?

I have two input fields (a & b), and a button, and a table where I want the contents of the input fields to be recorded and appended..

When I click the button, the first time it appends correctly, but the second time, the values in the the table are replaced

Please help me solve this in a way that maintains the records in table.

Thanks and regards
Prakash

Comment: Do you want to append to a table, shown in your current web page, or are you trying to use the `localStorage` feature of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in your append call, you are including `<tr>` along with the rest of the update.

Example:

```
$("#myTable").append("<tr><td>Content A</td><td>Content B</td>")
```